# Override parent style if child element exists

Tags: html, css

I want to overwrite parent's `z-index` for every child element containing a specific class.

There are two different class of children (w/c I can't change since it's generated by API).

First is a `.pop-up` and second one is a `.label`.
Both will be added under `#info`.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="info">
   <div class="pop-up">...</div>
</div>
<div id="info">
   <div class="label">...</div>
</div>
```

Due to different API actions, `.label` will sometimes be on top when it gets rendered recently. `#info`s `z-index` is **always** `110`.

Thus, I wanted to check if a child element exists (eg. `.label`) and update the parent's `z-index` to `109`.

Is this possible with `css3`? I can't do a hack via JS due to an "agreement".

This is what I've tried, but won't be able to update the parent's `z-index`

```
div#info > div.label {
   z-index: 109 !important;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: I think javascript is going to be required to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is unfortunately not possible with CSS3. This is because CSS3 **[lacks a parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)**.

It should be noted that this **will become** possible in **[CSS4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational)**, through dint of **[the `:has` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)**, where you would be able to target `#info` when it contains a label with:

```
div#info:has(div.label)
```

Comment: What is "dint"?

Comment: @connexo - "To indicate that something came about through a particular force or means" - [**Vocabulary.com**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dint). Essentially you can replace "through dint of" with "by means of". It may well be a region-specific thing though :)

Comment: I feel smarter already. :)

Comment: You mean "through dint" can be replaced by "by means of"? What if I only want to replace "dint", not "through dint"?

Comment: Please note that there has been discussion on `:has` going on since at least 2010, with several drafts being trashed because of the "single pass nature of CSS parsing". I'd replace "**will** become" by "*might* become".

Comment: @ObsidianAge, thanks for this. I've checked `:has` but unfortunately, it's not yet supported in Chrome and maybe is not supported yet at all.

Comment: I never thought my issue would turn out to be an English class. :)

Comment: closing this question. maybe you can check also my follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187076/overwrite-existing-styles-and-move-it-to-the-child-elements-style