# Override existing styles and move it to the child element's style

Tags: html, css

This is a follow-up question to - [Override parent style if child element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185739/overwrite-parent-style-if-child-element-exists)

As per suggestion and comments, `:has` is yet to be supported and there's no way to modify a parent's style if a certain child element exists.
Certainly not possible with just `css` alone.

I was thinking to pass down the `z-index` property to the child and unset it from the parent.

Here's what I've tried.

```
div#info {
   z-index: unset !important;
}

div#info > div.label {
   z-index: 109;
}

div#info > div.pop-up {
   z-index: 110; /* Pop-up should always appear on top */
}
```

But still didn't work. Is this even possible?

The idea is: making the parent element have no style and `z-index` will be declared in the child elements.

**NOTE**: by just using `CSS3`, no `scripts` involved. HTML elements and style properties are generated by the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working!

Given this **HTML Structure**:

```
<div id="info">
   <div class="pop-up">...</div>
</div>
<div id="info">
   <div class="label">...</div>
</div>
```

I just forced the parent to have no style properties and marked the `z-index` property for each child as `!important`

```
div#info {
   z-index: unset !important;
}

div#info > div.label {
   z-index: 109 !important;
}

div#info > div.pop-up {
   z-index: 110 !important; /* Pop-up should always appear on top */
}
```

This works for my need. Not sure if it will be useful in general since a parent may have different styles that will be inherited by the child element.

Good thing I only have to worry just one property, the `z-index`.